# Teaching programming for kids

Tags: ide, programming-languages, development-environment

I was wondering about the best approach/tools/languages/IDEs to be used for teaching kinds how to program.

I divided the ages as follows:

- 4-6

  6-9

  9-12

  12-5

  16+

Do you think the division is right? and what tool/language best suits for each group?

Comment: How many 4 years olds do you know that what to learn programming?

Comment: I think Stackoverflow isn't suited for such questions, because the answer is very subjective.

Comment: 6-9: Logo - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_%28programming_language%29

Comment: 4-6: Legos - Clear cut examples of Constructors and Deconstructors!

Comment: @CAbbott, I remember the turtle. Good times :)

Comment: I used to play with Microsoft Basic when I was very young, so I learned early how to use `goto` :)

Comment: I'm teaching kids vim + reactjs.. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 4-9 **Visual Programming Languages**

  - Scratch.mit.edu / Snap.berkeley.edu
  - LEGO Mindstorm
  - Any kind of visual language with basic commands
- 9-12

  - Alice this is a more advanced visual programming language dealing with 3d space and lighting.
  - **Basic Language**

    - BASIC
    - COBOL (I'd pick this one as it's still being used)
    - Visual Basic 6 (not vb.net) - This language is also used in excel macro's
    - Qbasic - Old dos programming language a lot of programmers started on.
    - any kind of language like that that is just one step up from assembly, so no complex things to understand
  - **Database**

    - If they want to get their hands wet in databases teach them access. Don't teach them very much though. This is a database for non programmers.
  - **Web Route**

    - HTML - very simple and rewarding
    - CSS - design for HTML
- 12-15

  - **Structural / Scripting based languages**

    - C
    - Python
    - PHP / Perl / Ruby
    - JavaScript
  - **Database: Basic SQL**

    - MySql
    - MSSql
- 16+ **High level languages**

  - c++ / c#
  - Java
  - any oo language
  - **Web Route**

    - jquery
    - knockout
    - angular
    - d3
  - **Database** - Best Processes

    - Foreign keys
    - Normalization
    - Performance
  - Oracle - is another database language, but should only be learned after they know all the database stuff mentioned above and a programming language.
  - Programming that works over a network

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks:) What about ALice/Scratch/logo? What you advice?

Comment: I don't know anything about those 3. ALice/Scratch/logo looks like it can be done at maybe 7+ Depending on how simple it is. At a younger age I feel like you might have better luck teaching maybe boolean logic or something? Maybe the concepts of programming more then any language.

Comment: This shows a very narrow perspective of what programming is.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I wasn't really narrowing it to any one language, more showing examples of increasing complexity in languages as they got older.